# Scheduled Communication between two Resource MicroServices

Tags: java, security, spring-boot, authorization, microservices

The scenario is I have two Resource Micro Services(Secured with Spring Security), let us assume A & B.
A wants to collect data from B on a scheduled way for ex A will call the B's endpoint every hour to collect some data.
The catch is two resource services can communicate with each other if they have a valid access token or we can say a user logged in.
But scheduled jobs have to run continuously independent of having a logged in User. So what should be the correct way to call B from A.

a. To have a configuration for a super default user to run scheduled jobs, authenticating implicitly?

NOTE: The scheduled job is independent of user intervention.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to keep all services outside of the world(**isolation on network level**) except one service which is the **single-entry point** for your clients where authentication/authorization handled. So you only need to implement security related operations/validations on that service than let client's request pass through other services.

Since you isolate your services from the world and **no security** implemented on rest of the services, you don't need token or validation for inter-service communication.

Answer (score 0):

When we´re working with API security the most used protocol is OAuth 2.0.

When dealing with client-service authentication/ authorization the most fit access token provisioning would be by Authorization Code Flow.

However, when dealing with service-to-service authentication / authorization the most fit access token provisioning would be by JWT Authorization Flow. Is this case the the requestor need to genereate a JWT token using a private key.

But if want to keep simple and the network restrictions are in place you could use a simple client credantials flow in OAuth.

***There are a interresting topic about handle batch processing with OAuth 2.0 in the nordicapi blog:***

http://nordicapis.com/how-to-handle-batch-processing-with-oauth-2-0/

For more information check the links bellow:

http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/

http://blog.monkey.codes/how-to-use-jwt-and-oauth-with-spring-boot/